# how to use order by field as well sort by id

Tags: php, mysql

i have the lot of data and i have to short data that has on Approval and Approval data with 
short id descending.

Like the following query:

```
 $query = "select * from event ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'Approval') desc";
```

But when new data added in event table. as when new data added in table its status is on Approval. and when i show the data .data is not sorted with event id descending.

I am confused how to use both order by field and order by id descending please help

Thanks and Regards

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'Approval') desc, id` ?

Comment: thanks @dfsq  i use as query  select * from event ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'Approval') desc,event_id desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as following if you want the Approval to appear first and then by descending order of id

```
select * from event 
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'Approval') desc ,event_id desc
```

Here is a real time example

```
mysql> select idusers from users where status = 'paid' order by idusers desc limit 1 ;
+---------+
| idusers |
+---------+
|  150949 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Above is to get the most recent paid user

```
mysql> select idusers,status from users order by field (status,'paid')desc , 
        idusers desc limit 3;
+---------+--------+
| idusers | status |
+---------+--------+
|  150949 | paid   |
|  150948 | paid   |
|  150947 | paid   |
+---------+--------+
```

In the above the most recent is the first row followed by others.

Comment: not work it show first status=active than short data for approval

Comment: Did you have `FIELD(status, 'Approval') desc` ?